# How to bypass deny direct access to edit link

Tags: form, content, editor, access

I managed to edit a file in controller to allow for the edit article link to be directly accessed if a user has a particular username. This is a core edit, but it's a local website only only my pc so I am not worried.

It works when I view in one Internet Explorer, but in another Internet Explorer it doesn't show the editor --only the input for the title. If I refresh the page it shows up.

I looked at `echo $this->form->getInput('articletext')` in **edit.php** and it is set to no editor when `var_dump()`. When I refresh,  the dump shows tiny_mce.

I can't for the life of me find what file or process sets the articletext editor nor what it bases it on (checks session or something). I know it would check the user's editor because tinymce is this user's default. It is also the site's default.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.
Right now I can't find how the editor is assigned in the php code. Otherwise I might be able to find what is missing from direct link to edit article.

I've compared some `var_dump`s of this form and `$this` params. I'm not seeing much of a difference from first view and refreshed view. Any advice?

---

#### Update1 :

Also the plugin is a nice idea but it seems likr a lot more work and learning curve. This is hard because i dont have home intetnet. But perhaps in the future i will merge it over to a plug in. If i can figure that all out.
For now mt only core hack is the controller.php in com_content. I dont know how to override only specific component controllers. Maybe I will check it out later if I have time. Thanks for all the advice everyone. For now all is working as i stated above.

Also for my origional post. I meant Internet Explorer. Which i assumed any one using joomla would know ie is short form of a browser name. I am typing on a small cellphone with limited time. Sorry for not proof reading. But anyways, i think the issue I had was less about the browser and more about settings.

I still cant find where joomla looks to see if a user has an editor set in their prefrence and to overrite the global configurations defualt editor with that of the users preferance. This would be nice, and I assumed this is default behaviour so I am not sure why when I edit an article on front end with super user the site ignores the users prefrence.

Anyways if any one can help shine some light on this, and again I hope i have time to make a plugin override direct access based on user group or name.

---

#### Update2:

Also i noticed that the global edior was none and showing rhat instead of users prefered esitor. Just changed defuakt to tinymce and it worked.

Comment: I understand that you are not too concerned with hacking core files, but the community of volunteers here care about supporting Joomla as much as we care about supporting your individual needs.  Every question is to be solved with the intent to help and educate not just you, but thousands of future researchers.  I hope that any volunteers that post an answer will go to the trouble of explaining a hack-free solution with best practices.  This is how Joomla gets better for everyone.

Comment: Please take a moment to post a careful answer that describes the steps that you took to resolve your issue.  Since your earlier posted answer was heavily downvoted, please add a new answer then award your own answer with a green tick so that your page is deemed resolved by the system.  Please do not post your solution as part of your question.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest you find a solution with a plugin. 
otherwise you run into lots of problems updating your joomla.
look at this https://docs.joomla.org/J3.x:Creating_an_Authentication_Plugin_for_Joomla

Comment: Please don't post link-only answers.  Your post looks more like a comment based on its quality.  When you have more reps you can comment.

Comment: Links are good, but they should merely supplement a solution.  See how my recent answer show a literal, specific solution in the post and offers links to support the advice.  https://joomla.stackexchange.com/a/24092/12352  Broadly recommending a plugin won't be much use to someone who has just come to Joomla.

Answer (score -4):

Got it to wotk well i thinkm i updated ie and editited content controller. Just added in a bariable to deny direct access if not in a super user group. Made a few other changes too. Im using this joomla only for one think on mt home pc. Never will update it. Its a dirty "fix".

Thanks for the help everyone.

Comment: Your answer needs more detail.  We are happy that you found a resolution, but the point of this site is to help more than one person.  Imagine if you were researching a similar issue, found this page and wanted to implement a solution, but the answer said: "I was able to fix my own problem.  I adjusted my code and now it works." <-- see how that is an utter waste of time to read? Please improve your question and answer.

Comment: Please take the Joomla Stack Exchange tour so that you can understand how to best interact with this community.   The better you understand this place the better it becomes for everyone.